# Bring modal to front

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Hey I am trying to bring this modal infront of the other elements on the page. 
I already tried  z-index: -1.

I would like to then implement this code on a adobe muse website and make the modal get an element from the selection of a combobox. 
Thank you for your help.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; front; /* Stay in place */  
     padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 600px; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #00A1E0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 511px;
height: 250px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;



</style>




<body>


<style>
div.background {

  border: 0px solid black;
div {
    background-color: #00A1E0;
    width: 511px;
}
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #00A1E0;
  border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 15%;
width: 511;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>





<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Add to shopping card
<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
<style>
#myBtn { color: #00A1E0; }
div.background {

  border: 0px #00A1E0;
div {
    background-color: #00A1E0;
    width: 511px;
}
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #FF530D;
 color: #00A1E0;
opacity: 80%;
width: 200;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00A1E0;
}
#myModal { background: ; }

</style>
</button>

    </div>



</head>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>you have added the classic business cards to the shopping cart</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

{

document.getElementById("resultSection").style.fontSize = "350%";



            document.getElementById("resultSection").innerHTML = "<H2></H2> " + result; 


                                               }
</script>
<style> #myBtn {  
     position: relative;



 font-size: 34px;

}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: fixed; front;` - that definitely is _not_ valid CSS. In fact you have numerous issues. Unclosed blocks. Missing property values. Nested blocks. Your CSS is a mess. Run it through a validator.

Comment: z-index of -1 will put it behind, the higher the z-index the further forward it will go

Comment: Splitting your code into two blocks, one for CSS and the other one for HTML would make it much easier to read. And possibly easier for you to modify.

Comment: is there a reason u don't go with the bootstrap modal? it provides everything  you need and you could just include it using some simple jquery. Furthermore you should realy rethink your indentation and general code cleanliness. it's such a mess it almost hurts  the readers eyes.

Comment: @Mr.Moe you are seriously suggesting using a very heavy library to display _one_ element? That is terrible advice. When ever somebody comments _"Just use bootstrap"_ it reminds me of [this meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/180262)

Comment: @Turnip as one can see in the provided code this programmer has some serious basic problems handling CSS and therefore, yes, I suggest using bootstrap as it not only helps with the problem that is currently accuring for him but also provides a quick an easy entry into CSS without the need to know intermediate tricks and complex styling structures. When he then got the basics and built some stuff with bootstrap he will find his way out of it to do something custom but till then ,Alexander Exner, just use bootstrap.
(at)Turnip nice meme tho ;)

Comment: That would be using Bootstrap as a crutch rather than learning how to do something properly. I stand by my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this - comments amended to show what I have changed

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place front is invalid - may break your css so removed */  
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box - don't know what this does?  If it is to move your modal down by 100px, then just change top below to 100px and remove this*/
    left: 0;
    right:0; /* Full width (left and right 0) */
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; /* Full height top and bottom 0 */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    z-index: 9999; /* Sit on top - higher than any other z-index in your site*/
}
```

You also have a missing end bracket from your `.close:hover` and `focus` and you seem to have a nested style within `div.background` - unless you are using a css pre-processor, then this is invalid css

Comment: Thank you very much I changed div.background. Also the modal is now in the front. Thank you very much !

Comment: I have another question I would like to make the background behind "Add to  shopping cart" in #00A1E0 and then have the text in Gray.

Comment: Sorry, just went for lunch - try this: `#myBtn { background-color: #00A1E0; color:gray; }`.  Also, you should probably consolidate all your styles into one style tag - or better still use a [stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html), makes for better maintainability

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful! I will get my CSS cleaned up.